# pg_upgrade oldbindir check fails

Tags: linux, postgresql, database-migration, pg-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade postgresql database from 9.1 to 9.4. I ran the 9.4 version of pg_upgrade as follows:

```
sudo -u postgres pg_upgrade -b <path>/postgres/9.1/bin -B <path>/postgres/9.4/bin -d <path>/9.1DBs/ -D <path>/<empty folder>
```

I get:

```
check failed for: <path>/postgres/9.1/bin Permission denied
```

The folder exists, I set the permissions to 777, even gave the postgres user ownership of the directory structure, but I'm still getting the same error.

Running in verbose mode does not provide any extra info.
The partition with that contains the old binaries is mounted under /media/ and I have read/write access.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: It's not sufficient that postgres have permissions in the last directory of the path. It needs to have `x` bit on every directory from the root down to the last directory of the path.

Comment: @DanielVérité That's it! Why don't you make it an answer so I can close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error

> check failed for: /postgres/9.1/bin Permission denied

happens because access permission on directories (`x` bit) need to be set in every directory in the hierarchy, from the root to the directory containing these executables files.

This is detailed at Unix.SE in:

[Do the parent directory's permissions matter when accessing a subdirectory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13858)